# Use xDs as a generic control plane

Tags: envoyproxy, servicemesh

While xDs was proposed as the control plane for Envoy (and later on gRpc), the [protocol](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-docs/xds_protocol#basic-protocol-overview) itself is very generic. Resource are represented by resource types, and the resource content are encoded as proto.Any. As such, I feel that if I have a xDs server, I can extend it to deliver resource types unrelated to Envoy or gRpc.

Has anyone tried this? What are the pros and cons for the xDs protocol as a generic control plane?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely!gRPC is a great example of using the protocol beyond Envoy.

As long as your client is xDS adherent (meaning it can receive and follows the protocol specs), you could theoretically send any sort of payload over.

With regards to pros/cons, I'd say that's use case specific. In the [go-control-plane](https://github.com/envoyproxy/go-control-plane) we allow for shipping of generic resources and custom types to Envoy. This is helpful when users write custom logic/extensions and need to use this library as a shipping mechanism.

One major thing I might add, using a well tested and adopted protocol like xDS does provide value add knowing it has had its issues worked out.